# How to solve Harmonic oscillator numerically?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I am trying to solve, using MATLAB, the time dependent Harmonic oscillator equation numerically. But I have no idea how to even get started as I have never learned this method in university:

X'' + w(t)^2 X = 0

[image: X'' + w(t)^2 X = 0]

with boundary conditions X_0 = 1, X_0' = 0 and Y_0 = 0, Y'_0 = 1

Comment: What does Y have to do with anything? And can you fix up your differential equation, which doesn't look complete? Have you looked at the examples in the ode45( ) doc?

Comment: Maybe that `y` refers to that usual thing you do to transform an 2nd (or higher) order ODE into a system of first order ODEs (i.e. `y = x'`)? Then the equation would be `x' = y; y' = -w(t) * x +...` or something.

Answer (score 0):

1. `ode45` is a good start point.

Basic examples :

```
clear;close all;clc

tspan=[0 100];     % time
x_init=[5;0];       % known initial conditions

[t,y] = ode45(@vdp1,tspan,x_init);

figure(1)
plot(t,y(:,1),'r',t,y(:,2),'b')
grid on
title('Solution with ODE45');
xlabel('Time t');
ylabel('Solution y');
legend('y_1','y_2')

f=.5
[t,y] = ode45(@(t,y) vdp2(t,y,f),tspan,x_init);

figure(2)
plot(t,y(:,1),'r',t,y(:,2),'b')
grid on
title(['Solution with ODE45 and f = ' num2str(f)]);
xlabel('Time t');
ylabel('Solution y');
legend('y_1','y_2')
```

support functions:

```
function dydt = vdp1(t,y)
%
f=.1;
dydt = [y(2); sin(2*pi*f*t)*y(1)];

function dydt = vdp2(t,y,f)
%
dydt = [y(2); sin(2*pi*f*t)*y(1)];
```

[image]

[image]

---

2. This: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/69951-runge-kutta-fixed-step-solvers?s_tid=srchtitle_harmonic%2520oscillator_81 among other examples has example1 solving damped and driven harmonic oscillators
3. And another harmonic oscillator solution with ODE solver:

https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/83233-matlab_program_solving_odes_harmonic_oscillators?s_tid=srchtitle_harmonic%20oscillator_9

4. You can also solve with symbolic expressions, this is Loren's post comparing symbolic and numerical solving

https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2010/04/08/odes-from-symbolic-to-numeric-code/?s_tid=srchtitle_harmonic%2520oscillator_105

5. I find the following concise introduction to ODE solving by Cleve Moler more useful than some full year university modules.

https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2016/11/14/my-favorite-ode/?s_tid=srchtitle_harmonic%2520oscillator_131

6. When solving oscillators in polar coordinates you may need to have a look at

https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2017/11/06/three-term-recurrence-relations-and-bessel-functions/?s_tid=srchtitle_harmonic%2520oscillator_140

In point 6 there's a wonderful introduction to Bessel functions and their zeros.